# Checking if input box is empty using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I just wanted to ask how can we check if the value of an input box is empty using Python, on the image below, I wanted to check the input box if empty and print some values if the statement is true also if it is false. Currently it is error because of the value (note that I did not put any value as indicated in the image with boxed red).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to evaluate if the value attribute is an empty string

```
if pashu == "":
```

Comment: Sorry Sir, i am new. how? Can i just comment or therre is a button for it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am little late, but I'll try to help.

You can use the `isspace()` and `""` (empty string).

```py
if isspace(pashu) == True or pashu == "":
    print("This is empty")
else:
    print("continue")
```

Did this help?

Answer (score 0):

Expression:

```python
bool('')
```

Returns `False`. Expression:

```python
bool('a')
```

Returns `True`. Thats mean you can check if string is empty by conversion to bool. `if` statement does is automatically.

```python
if pashu:
    print('this is empty')
```